# Work Experience Mistake on a Resume

Tags: interviewing, resume, hiring-process

About month-and-a-half ago, I submitted my resume and an application for an analyst position. I had some voluntary work experience which I listed under "Professional Experience." Later did I notice my mistake before fixing it. Plus I was just learning to put a doable resume at the time. But by then, I had already completed my phone screening process and it has been over three weeks since I completed my formal interview process. Since I noticed my mistake almost two weeks after my formal interview, I don't know what to do. I updated my resume and submitted to new positions within the same company which directly states which of my work experience was "voluntary" and which was "professional." But still, the interviewing manager still has my dated resume.

Now, I am really panicking. I really want this job and I want to clarify my mistake but I don't know what to do. Any advice from hiring managers would be great. This company I applied to is a major bank. I would also welcome any response and advice from others as well.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure they've figured out that it was an unintentional mistake, so panic seems excessive. They know you're human, and they've probably made similar mistakes themselves. (Heck, I just made a doozy of a mistake last week, getting two files confused with each other. I'm probably gonna have to abase myself before the client and make sure they blame me rather than the company.)

On the other hand... it probably wouldn't hurt, and might help, to contact them and say "I just noticed that I sent you a version of my resume that still had an editing mistake in it. If I'm still being considered for that position, I'd like to send a corrected resume. Who should I address it to?"

Comment: I was offered an interview with a company on the basis of a CV that contained an error.  I didn't become aware of the mistake until a couple of months after I'd been hired.  You can imagine how awkward THAT was.  I came clean and revealed my mistake to my boss and he was (luckily) fine about it.  Legality and morality aside, I don't think I could've worked there with something like that hanging over me.  In this situation, honesty is the best policy.

Answer (score 1):

I first started my career as a systems engineer by volunteering at a non-profit. I put my experience under "Work Experience" because that's what it was work experience. Yes, it was unpaid, but I did the work. Once I got the experience, the next job was a full-time, salaried gig.

You can clarify that the job was a volunteer ASAP. You'll need to clarify that with HR first since they are the ones who will do the background check on you. Emphasize to them that although the work was volunteer, you still got work experience out of it and, hopefully, you can provide references for that volunteer position. Ditto with the people you interviewed with.